# How to confirm alert box of specific terminal window id?

Tags: applescript

I am starting a new terminal window from a terminal:

`osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "myProgram.sh"'`

Since the new process is not ending(it is basically a server), I want to be able to stop it  at some point using AppleScript.

I was thinking of the best solution to just kill the process by id, but I have multiple instances of the program started(it is a node.js server) and I cannot differentiate them by name, therefore I cannot get the PID of the correct process instance using `ps -ef`.

If I do:

`osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to close window id {windowId}'`

I am getting the alert box `"Do you want to terminate running process...?"`.

1. Is it possible to get PID of terminal window id(I cannot execute any commands(like `echo $$`) inside the terminal window as there is a running process)?
2. If not 1., is it possible to force close the window id?
3. If not 2., how can I confirm this alert box using AppleScript?

Comment: Would it be easier to `pkill myProgram.sh` or similar?

Comment: @nohillside, that would be great, but I can't find the process id so easily. I updated the question with more information.

Comment: pkill goes by name (more or less), not by id. Run `ps aux` to see the actual name (and maybe have a look at `man pkill`).

Comment: okay, but I can have multiple running instances of `myProgram` and I don't want to kill them all. I want to be able to differentiate them, and all that comes to my mind is that window id is the only way

Comment: Why not just turn off the configuration prompt in Terminal?

Comment: @MarcWilson, yes, this is what I did for now, but it is not the optimal solution as it is something one must remember or describe in documentation that it must be done in our project.

Comment: Well, the method you should really use is set things up so you can pass a message to the process, and have it close itself.  Not kill it from outside.

Comment: You are right, but I mislead you a bit - the server I am starting is not written by us, so I don't have control over its implementation. Anyway, thanks for your time!

Comment: Double post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71777884/how-to-force-close-terminal-window-id-using-applescript